# Multiple Thread Variable Access

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am running two seperate threads(Android SDK) a main thread and another that counts the number of state changes on a digital input sensor. I wish to access the state change count in the main thread to send the data elsewhere. Am I able to suspend the sensor thread, pass the value using a getter, then resume the thread? I would also like to reset the counter after sampling (using a setter?).

What is the best practice to implement this?

Comment: how does the thread that counts the number of state changes on a digital input sensor works? Does it sleeps periodically, or does the sensor notifies it somehow?

Comment: `wait()`, `sleep()` etc.

Comment: it waits for a high value. then adds to a counter. Then repeats

Answer (score 0):

This resembles close to producer consumer problem. You can have a single length Blocking queue.

**Main thread -- consumer**

**Other thread (which counts state changes) --producer**

*Java API to solve producer consumer problem :* **BlockingQueue**

Read value in other thread, and place it in a BlockingQueue(size 1). Main thread will check the queue and read the value. Once value is read 'other thread' can again put a new value.This will guarantee that your value is read by main thread and then reset.

API : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

If the count is an `int`, you can just access it from the main thread without a problem.

Comment: yer its an int, but do I have to lock it at all?

Comment: No need to lock the int. Incrementing an int is an atomic operation, you'll get the right value for the time of the read (as much as there is a right value for concurrent updates...)

Answer (score 0):

You should use synchronized key word which may guarantee that you peace of code is accessed with only one thread at the same time. 
Here is a link with more details that describes a use case similar to yours: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html